# How to get all links from a website by className, split the website name, and store within an array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get all the links from Gmail and store them within an array. I'm trying to get all the emails to be stored as such -

- [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
- [www.samsung.com](http://www.samsung.com)
- [www.random-website.com](http://www.random-website.com)
- [www.facebook.ru](http://www.facebook.ru)
- [www.just-eat.co.uk](http://www.just-eat.co.uk)

```
function gmailGetAllLinks(){
  var classname = document.getElementsByClassName('AO');
  var array1 = [];
  for(i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
      var str = classname[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
      var res = str.split("?"); 
      array1.push(res[0]);

  }
  window.alert(array1)
  warningPopup()
}
```

When I try to print the array out as `phishingWebsites.append = array1;` it shows as just null, where doing `window.alert` shows only the first link.

Comment: `append()` is a function. Please provide some sample html as per [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to use `querySelectorAll('.AO a')` to target all those anchors.

Then you can turn that collection into an array and use `Array#map()` to get the results

```js
function gmailGetAllLinks(){
  const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.AO a')).map(link => {
      const url = new URL(link.href);
      url.search = '';
      return url.toString();
  })
  
 console.log(links)
}

gmailGetAllLinks()
```

```css
.AO{ padding: 1em; border:2px solid #ccc; margin: 1em}
a{display: block; margin-bottom:1em}
```

```html
<div class="AO">
  <a href="https://google.com?q=foo">Google</a>
  <a href="https://samsung.com?q=foo">Samsung</a>
</div>

<div class="AO">
  <a href="https://facebook?q=foo">Facebook</a>
  <a href="https://wikipedia.com?q=foo">Wikipedia</a>
</div>
```